# Creating a dotfile script

Tags: bash, dot-files

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403255/symlink-dotfiles-with-a-script) over on SO and didn't get very far; here is the current version of my script and what I'd like the do. Suggestions for debugging and testing are what I'm looking for. I'll probably remove `-fn` while working on this more, as it just gets in the way - had to move files into a temp directory and then back again in order for anything to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function makeLinks() {
    ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile\
    ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig\
    ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitignore_global ~/.gitignore_global
    source ~/.bash_profile;
    }

    read -rp "This may overwrite existing files. Are you sure? (y/n) " -n 1;
    echo "";
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        makeLinks
    fi;
```

Comment: remove trailing blackslashes

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment: the trailing backslashes cause the three `ln` commands to be treated as one line. You don't want that. You want three different lines. So, when I echo the three lines here is how they are parsed.

```
$ echo ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile\
>     ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig\
>     ln -sfn ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitignore_global ~/.gitignore_global
ln -sfn /cygdrive/d/home/prateek/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile /cygdrive/d/home/prateek/.bash_profile ln -sfn /cygdrive/d/home/prateek/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitconfig /cygdrive/d/home/prateek/.gitconfig ln -sfn /cygdrive/d/home/prateek/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitignore_global /cygdrive/d/home/prateek/.gitignore_global
```

You can see as the output of the `echo` all the commands are listed on one line. Removing the backslashes won't cause that behavior. Each command will be treated separately.